# Incorrect Bool Value

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I am parsing a JSON string:

```
Response: {"success":false,"displaymessage":"UserName or Email already exist. Please try again"}
```

The code I am using is:

```
  NSLog(@"Result: %@ %@", [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"success"]? @"YES" : @"NO", [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"displaymessage"]);
```

However my out put is:

```
Result: YES UserName or Email already exist. Please try again
```

I should be getting a No. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `valueForKeyPath:` method returns an object, which is always non-nil (hence you're seeing a `YES` instead of a `NO`). If I remember it correctly, booleans are wrapped in `NSNumber`. You should pull the actual boolean value from the object returned by `valueForKeyPath:`, like this:

```
[[responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"success"] boolValue]? @"YES" : @"NO"
```